# Getting a blob content using user delegation SAS created using user delegation key

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have created an AAD app as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app.

The access is given to the azure storage account for the AAD app created.

Got the client id and client secret.

To create a user delegation key and user delegation sas, I am using the approach and code as defined in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet.

(set environment variables as mentioned in article).

I am able to generate the user delegation key using method GetUserDelegationSasBlob.

The container and blob file is existing one.

Now I am using the method ReadBlobWithSasAsync to read the contents of the blob using the SAS uri as generated above.

But, I get error as below.

> This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this
>   permission. RequestId:5d127eaf-101e-00be-6666-6a3875000000
>
> Time:2019-09-13T19:04:15.4109144Z
>
> Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation
>   using this permission.)
>
> ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

In another approach, I am generating the user delegation key using rest api.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-user-delegation-key

I am able to get user delegation key in xml format.
I am creating SAS from it as per steps in 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas

For signature, I am using this code, using StringToSign and secret value as received from delegation key.

```
var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(ToSign);
using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
{
    byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
    String sig= Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
}
```

I am doing the GET request.
I have tried various set of parameter values, like,

sr: b and c
sks: b and c
sp: racwd and r and rw and few more

skv and sv is 2018-11-09 because this version is required for creating user delegation key.

But the GET api returns the error.

> `AuthenticationFailed`
>       Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the
>   signature. RequestId:e4bc8f0f-d01e-0046-7367-6af368000000
>   Time:2019-09-13T19:12:27.7780695Z
>       Signature fields not well formed.

Comment: Try to assign the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to the storage account. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#assign-the-reader-role-for-portal-access).

Comment: Hi Joey. Can't see the check mark beside your comment.

Comment: Hi Manish, just click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in, like this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SY6O.png).

Comment: Hi Joey. Thanks for helping to resolve the issue. Accepted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to assign the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role to the storage account.

The `Reader` role is an Azure Resource Manager role that permits users to view storage account resources, but not modify them. **It does not provide read permissions to data** in Azure Storage, but only to account management resources.

Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#assign-the-reader-role-for-portal-access).